# Using google apis in firebase funcion

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

I would like to use the google iot core api from a firebase function. 
It all works, but it is very slow. I think is due to the authentication process that needs to be carried out one very call. Is there a way to speed this up?

Right now I have this:

```
function getClient(cb) {
    const API_VERSION = 'v1';
    const DISCOVERY_API = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest';
    const jwtAccess = new google.auth.JWT();
    jwtAccess.fromJSON(serviceAccount);
    // Note that if you require additional scopes, they should be specified as a
    // string, separated by spaces.
    jwtAccess.scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform';
    // Set the default authentication to the above JWT access.
    google.options({ auth: jwtAccess });
    const discoveryUrl = `${DISCOVERY_API}?version=${API_VERSION}`;
    google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl, {}).then( end_point => {
        cb(end_point);
    });
}
```

And this allows me to do:

```
export function sendCommandToDevice(deviceId, subfolder, mqtt_data) {
    const cloudRegion = 'europe-west1';
    const projectId = 'my-project-id;
    const registryId = 'my-registry-id';

    getClient(client => {
        const parentName = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${cloudRegion}`;
        const registryName = `${parentName}/registries/${registryId}`;
        const binaryData = Buffer.from(mqtt_data).toString('base64');
        const request = {
            name: `${registryName}/devices/${deviceId}`,
            binaryData: binaryData,
            subfolder: subfolder
        };
        client.projects.locations.registries.devices.sendCommandToDevice(request,
            (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Could not update config:', deviceId);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

The way that I've found to speed it up is to avoid doing the authentication. I've solved it doing this:

```
const google = new GoogleApis();
const API_VERSION = 'v1';
const DISCOVERY_API = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest';
const jwtAccess = new google.auth.JWT();
jwtAccess.fromJSON(serviceAccount);
// Note that if you require additional scopes, they should be specified as a
// string, separated by spaces.
jwtAccess.scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform';
// Set the default authentication to the above JWT access.
google.options({ auth: jwtAccess });
const discoveryUrl = `${DISCOVERY_API}?version=${API_VERSION}`;
var googleClient;
google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl, {}).then( client => {
    //cb(end_point);
    googleClient = client;
});

// Returns an authorized API client by discovering the Cloud IoT Core API with
// the provided API key.
function getClient(cb) {
    cb(googleClient);
}
```

But when happens then when the client expires? Is there any good solution from using google apis from firebase functions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the discovery pieces. There's a direct IoT Core admin REST API, so you don't have to use discovery...I think. I haven't worked with the Firebase Functions, but they're roughly equivalent to the Google Cloud Functions which may end up working here also. The code we (in a live demo we did) ran to do what you're doing is [here](https://github.com/GabeWeiss/GoogleIoTCoreApp/blob/master/gcf/updateIoTConfig/index.js) if you wanted to tinker around and see if you can get this running in a Firebase Function.